# Accessing the raw bytes of a processed ActiveStorage::Variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to include a [variant of a file stored in Active Storage](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.2/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb) as an inline attachment for a mailer. The mailer side of things isn't important; I'm trying to read the bytes of an uploaded image.

To include the original uploaded file, this works:

```
# The model
class Newsletter < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :header
end

# The mailer
class NewsletterMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def mailshot
    @newsletter = params[:newsletter]
    if @newsletter.header.attached?
      attachments.inline['header'] = @newsletter.header.download
    end
  end
end

# In the view (MJML HAML, but you get the idea...)
- if attachments['header'].present?
  %mj-image{src: attachments['header'].url}
```

But what if instead of [including the original file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.2/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L162-L166), I want to include a resized variant of it?

```
attachments.inline['header'] =
  @newsletter
    .header
    .variant(resize: '100x100')
    .processed
    .???
```

How do I access the raw bytes of the processed image?

I can of course still `.download` the original and do my own processing, but rather hoping there might be an easier way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question, and [reading the code a little more](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.2/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb#L71), I can do it like this:

```
if @newsletter.header.attached?
  processed = @newsletter.header.variant(resize: '100x100').processed
  attachments.inline['header'] = processed.service.download processed.key
end
```

It feels like there should be a more elegant way?

Comment: Dude, you just saved my butt! Yes, there probably should be a more elegant way. Sadly I searched for several hours before finally finding this. Thank you so much!

Comment: This solution is awesome. Well done for finding that. Who would have believed that the simple requirement of downloading a variant of an image in ActiveStorage would have proved so complex and obscure though?